# How to copy everything in an html elements, text and style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery page that I built.  The crucial parts all lie within a div like so..

```
<div id="TestDiv"></div>
<div id="randomDialogName"></div>
<div id="randomDialogName"></div>
<div id="randomDialogName"></div>
<div id="randomDialogName"></div>
</body>
```

within the TestDive there can be lots of elements, charts, grids, live handlers and etc.  (Mostly jQueryUI Elements)

What I would like to do is select everything within "TestDiv" copy it to a variable as a temporary measure then when I load the data back into TestDiv, I would like to reload everything the way it was.  Like so.

```
function saveDivElements(){
    var saveId = $('#TestDiv').attr('tab');
    var html = $('#TestDiv').html(); //have tried clone(true) and other methods here
    console.log(html);
    setLoaded(saveId, true, html); //saves to divData member variable on page
}

$("#TestDiv").html(divData); // called later and loads data
```

What I have currently, saves the elements, but there is no class information or handlers that are saved.  So on reload the elements are there, but nothing else remains.  I need something where I don't have to reload all the handlers, reset all the buttons.  (Also this runs locally, performance is not an issue)

Comment: What do you mean by "on resume"?

Comment: When I reload the data back into the div.

Comment: So, you want to save a certain state and restore it after it was changed? Can you provide a jsFiddle or something?

Comment: Yup pretty much.  One sec.

Comment: wouldn't It be better to serialize the data to localstorage (or every other storage) and serialize from with a template of some kind?

Comment: please don't use the same id on several elements.

Comment: Eru - never do that, hence the randomDialogName.. was supposed to mean several dialogs..

alonisser - that is what I am doing in almost every instance just needed this to work for this instance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you utilize [.detach()](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) instead of extracting the raw HTML?

```
var savedChildren = $('#TestDiv').children().detach();
```

It takes along with it anything that you have bound to the elements. Here is a basic example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TkAEA/).